# How to make Eigensystem in version 10 produce the same results as version 9

Tags: linear-algebra, version-10

The Eigensystem in version 10 seems to give slightly different results as in version 9:

```
Hmtx={{12.375, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 - 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 - 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 - 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, 5.9846202809437726*^-18 - 1.8774107494749925*^-17*I, -5.0917886236526596*^-17 - 3.6443855725102797*^-17*I, -1.7364763179227213*^-17 + 5.2457065058860084*^-17*I}, {-0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 7.875, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 - 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 - 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 - 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, 5.9846202809437726*^-18 - 1.8774107494749925*^-17*I, -5.0917886236526596*^-17 - 3.6443855725102797*^-17*I}, {-1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 4.375, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 - 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 - 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 - 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, 5.9846202809437726*^-18 - 1.8774107494749925*^-17*I}, {7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 1.8749999999999998, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 - 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 - 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 - 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I}, {3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 0.3749999999999999, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 - 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 - 2.208718528794109*^-18*I}, {6.284659706684547*^-19 + 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -0.12500000000000014, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 - 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I}, {-1.2338675571278232*^-17 + 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 + 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 0.3749999999999999, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I}, {-4.6634340043469916*^-18 + 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 + 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 + 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 1.8749999999999998, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 + 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I}, {5.9846202809437726*^-18 + 1.8774107494749925*^-17*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 + 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 + 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 + 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 4.375, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 - 4.417437057588218*^-18*I}, {-5.0917886236526596*^-17 + 3.6443855725102797*^-17*I, 5.9846202809437726*^-18 + 1.8774107494749925*^-17*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 + 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 + 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 + 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 7.875, -0.06250000000000006 - 8.834874115176436*^-18*I}, {-1.7364763179227213*^-17 - 5.2457065058860084*^-17*I, -5.0917886236526596*^-17 + 3.6443855725102797*^-17*I, 5.9846202809437726*^-18 + 1.8774107494749925*^-17*I, -4.6634340043469916*^-18 + 1.1043592643970545*^-18*I, -1.2338675571278232*^-17 + 2.208718528794109*^-18*I, 6.284659706684547*^-19 + 2.6504622345529306*^-17*I, 3.5296840598063115*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, 7.507272729062478*^-19 - 2.4295903816735198*^-17*I, -1.1548235516929313*^-17 + 4.417437057588218*^-18*I, -0.06250000000000006 + 8.834874115176436*^-18*I, 12.375}};

{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem[Hmtx];
vals
vecs[[1]]
```

in version 9 I get:

eigenvalue

```
(*
{12.3759, 12.3759, 7.87525, 7.87525, 4.37545, 4.37545, 1.87605, 1.87604, 0.387613, 0.372399, -0.140221}
*)
```

first eigenvector

```
(*
{-0.000534641 + 0.00179264 I, 7.42495*10^-6 - 0.0000248957 I, -5.80038*10^-8 + 1.94486*10^-7 I,  3.45242*10^-10 - 1.15759*10^-9 I, -1.71049*10^-12 +  6.02886*10^-12 I, -1.68042*10^-11 - 3.01451*10^-14 I,  3.36278*10^-9 + 1.56589*10^-16 I, -6.45683*10^-7 + 1.38957*10^-18 I, 0.00010848 - 5.32021*10^-19 I, -0.0138864 -  1.97975*10^-18 I, 0.999902}
*)
```

in version 10 I get:

eigenvalue

```
(*
{12.3759 - 1.02031*10^-15 I, 12.3759 - 9.91618*10^-29 I, 7.87525 - 8.85813*10^-16 I, 7.87525 - 4.21836*10^-20 I,  4.37545 + 8.4819*10^-17 I, 4.37545 + 8.48193*10^-17 I, 1.87605 - 9.81335*10^-20 I, 1.87604 - 9.81346*10^-20 I,  0.387613 - 1.396*10^-22 I,  0.372399 - 1.40297*10^-22 I, -0.140221 - 1.24838*10^-24 I}
*)
```

first eigenvector

```
(*
{-0.00639256 + 0.0131895 I,  0.0000887781 - 0.000183172 I, -6.93536*10^-7 + 1.43094*10^-6 I,  4.12798*10^-9 - 8.51706*10^-9 I, -2.14113*10^-11 +   4.43576*10^-11 I, -1.67039*10^-11 - 2.21781*10^-13 I,  3.36242*10^-9 + 1.15472*10^-15 I, -6.45615*10^-7 + 1.42743*10^-17 I,  0.000108469 - 7.67751*10^-17 I, -0.0138849 - 4.92661*10^-16 I,  0.999796 + 0. I}
*)
```

How can I make version 10 produce the same results as version 9? How can I know which method is used in version 9? I tried to set the `Method` options in version 10 but still unable to get an agreement.

**Edit**

I agree that the comments are all right, that they are both correct results. I'm curious what's the change in the "internal mechanism", method, etc, so that it produce different correct results. I use this Eigensystem in calculating some quantum mechanic problem called high harmonic generation, which is very sensitive to small errors in the results. In theory , an overall phase change should not effect my results, but after upgrading to version 10, the noise floor in my results increase more then one order of magnitude. I'm trying to see why that happens, and this is my first stop.

Mathematica is now a language, I guess I would expect to have exactly the same results if I update the "compiler", or at least I should know why the results are different.

Comment: Does `Chop` help?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The eigenvector seems quite different.

Comment: It's good to mention that both results are correct (there are degenerate eigenvalues).

Comment: @xslittlegrass: The eigenvectors are different in V9 and V10. However, they are both correct, despite being different. Your matrix has a degenerate spectrum, and thus the degenerate eigenspace decompositions are subject to arbitrariness depending on the internal architecture used in the computation. This is not a bug, and should be expected.

Comment: Also, I noticed that `Max[Abs[Im[Hmtx]]]` is on the order of machine precision, and that the matrix appears to be real symmetric with the exception of what looks like machine-precision Hermitian noise, so you can simplify it quite a bit using `Chop[Hmtx]`.

Comment: You Hamiltonian has degenerate eigenvalues, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52293/16). I am guessing this is a single particle in a harmonic oscillator potential (`ListPlot[Diagonal[Chop@Hmtx]]`), in which case the degeneracy is physically due to the reflection symmetry of the potential. If you plot the absolute value of the eigenvectors (the density) you'll see what is going on and why hybridisation is so weak.

Comment: @Jens I think here it really is due to degeneracies. It would have been useful to have a canonical question and answer to this somewhere.

Comment: @acl Right - your answer to the other question (which got  closed) could perhaps be combined with mine to give a canonical answer. If xslittlegrass rephrases the question to be more general maybe it could remain open to serve that purpose... (sorry I have to leave right now...)

Comment: Actually, your Hamiltonian is literally that of a SHO on a 1d lattice (plus noise). You can find analytical solutions to this [here](http://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.72.033616) or [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503477), although I'm not sure how useful they are to you.

Comment: @acl Good catch! Yes, I'm solving a 1d lattice hamiltonian! I'm curious how did you know that? The closed form can be written in terms of Mathieu functions (also discussed in The Mathematica GuideBooks), but is only limited to this special potential. Plus, I'm interested in the time-dependent dynamics, so I need the numerical results.

Comment: @xslittlegrass right, I know the closed form solution from the papers I cited (that's where I first saw them, but I am not sure if they first appeared elsewhere). If you're interested in general potentials and/or time dependent solutions then you indeed have to do it this way (numerically). As to how I knew it, I guess it's like asking "wow how did you know this is the Schrodinger equation?" isn't it? Now, if you had an interacting Hamiltonian and I spotted the potential, that would have indeed been noteworthy :)

Comment: @xslittlegrass: Off-topic, but I downloaded your PovrayRender.m file, and attempted to run it on your first example from your blog using the directory to my Windows executable for Pov-Ray by executing `p = SphericalPlot3D[
  1 + 2 Cos[2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 80];
povrayRender[p, "C:\\Program \
Files\\POV-Ray\\v3.7\\bin\\pvengine64.exe"]` but it just gave a "File not found during Import" error. Am I using the correct filepath to Pov-Ray?

Comment: I also tried `povrayRender[p, "C:\Program Files\POV-Ray\v3.7\bin\pvengine.exe"]`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Thanks for letting me know. I only tested mac and linux before. I'll test windows when I get home.

Comment: I figured out what the problem was, it's doing something wrong with the filepaths (and I forgot to insert escape sequences for the space in "Program Files"), seems to work fine.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus good to hear that :)